# Keep getting Login_info not defined error. Tried several different solutions

Tags: python

**cannot for the life of me seem to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried to make the variable global aswell as relocating it. It seems the issue is that the variable (Login_info) isn't defined in the correct position however I cannot think of the correct location. Thanks! (I left allot of the code out because it won't let me post this thread otherwise.)**

```
File "C:\Python\Username+Password\Main.py", line 20, in Register
    UserNameReg()
  File "C:\Python\Username+Password\Main.py", line 36, in UserNameReg
    login_info == line.split()
NameError: name 'login_info' is not defined
is the error log im getting.
```

````
def Register():
    global username
    username = str(input("What would you like your username to be (make sure to make it 8+ characters!):\n"))
    username.strip()
    UserNameReg()

def UserNameReg():
    for line in open("Username.py","r").readlines():
        global login_info
        login_info == line.split()
        if username == login_info[0]:
            UserNameMultAccCheck = ("Sorry that username is already registered! Type 'A' to retry or 'B' to Login!")
            UserNameMultAccCheck.lower().strip()
            if UserNameMultAccCheck == ("a"):
                print ("Retrying....")
                time.sleep(1)
                Register()
            elif UserNameMultAccCheck == ("b"):
                print ("Redirecting....")
                time.sleep(1)
                Login()
            else:
                print ("Sorry I didn't catch that; Redirecting to Registry.....")
                time.sleep(1)
                Register()
        elif username == (""):
            print ("Sorry I didn't quite catch that, Redirecting to Registry.....")  
            time.sleep(1)
            Register()

        else:
            file.write(username)
            file.write(" ")
            print ("Username Available!")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            PassWord()

def PassWord():
    password = str(input("Please input your desired password "))
    for line in open("Username.py","r").readlines():
        if password <= len(8):
            PassWordLenDeny = input("Sorry That Password isn't long enough. Would you like to A)Retry or B)Restart the Registry process?")
            PassWordLenDeny.strip().lower()
            if PassWordLenDeny == ("a"):
                print ("Retrying...")
                time.sleep(1)
                PassWord()
            elif PassWordLenDeny == ("b"):
                print ("Restarting....")
                time.sleep(1)
                Register()
            else:
                print("Sorry I didn't catch that, Restarting the Registry process.....")
                time.sleep(1)
                Register()
        elif password > len(8):
            print ("Password accepted! Redirecting to login page!")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            file = open("UserName.py","a")
            file.write(password)
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
            Login()           


def Log_Reg():
    Log_RegRequest = input("Would you like to:\nA)Log into an account\nB)Register an account")
    Log_RegRequest.lower().strip()
    if Log_RegRequest == ("a"):
        if Login() == True:
            MenuDef()
            if Menu == "":
                MenuDef()
    elif Log_RegRequest == ("b"):
        print ("Great! Registering.....")
        time.sleep(1)
        Register()
    else:
        print ("Sorry I didn't quite catch that.")
        Log_Reg()```
````

Comment: You should post the stack trace that includes the error so we can see where it's being thrown. Also, use a name in your question instead of just saying "the variable", so we know which one you mean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.